# PHP File Upload problems when uploading "larger" (over 2MB) files

Tags: php, forms, apache, upload

I am having problems trying to upload "larger" files, and I believe the limit that I'm allowed is about 2MB. I've uploaded multiple filetypes below 2MB (.js, .png, .jpg, .psd, .php), however anything over about 2MB fails.

- 1.8MB psd image worked
- 2.4MB psd image didnt' work (same file as 1.8, just bigger)

I've already changed php.ini to the following:

- upload_max_filesize = 20M (changed this from 2M)
- post_max_size = 40M (changed this from 2M)
- max_execution_time = 60 (changed this from 45)
- max_input_time = 180 (changed this from 30)
- memory_limit = 48M (Changed this from 8M)

I've also added the following to my htaccess file in both the final directory where I'd like the file to be moved, and the initial directory where the upload form lives:

- LimitRequestBody 53687091

Like I mentioned, the upload is working for smaller files, so I believe it has to be a restriction on the upload size, not anything wrong with the form.

Any ideas as to where I can look next? I want the limit to be 20M, it's all on our backend with a login required to access the page, so I am not worried about rouge uploads.

Comment: Depending on how your server is configured you may need to restart the web server service for your changes to take effect. Also, what does a phpinfo(); page show?

Comment: is there an actual error that is being thrown? Or does the page just 'expire' and not result in a "file uploaded" result? Maybe its your code that does a check for size and not the server software?

Comment: The error is just my custom form error saying the upload didn't complete, no error from apache or php or anything.

Comment: Can you post the code you're using for the form and the processing script? (and if you're comfortable with it, your phpinfo() print out? Also (long shot), are there any timed events (js) running on the page? I ran into a similar problem a few years ago, and it turned out that there was an setinterval event was interrupting the upload.

Answer (score 4):

Confirm that your upload_max_filesize / post_max_size is INDEED updated.
Sometimes users don't know which `php.ini` file to edit.

Best way is to create file (that you delete later) and add the following code:

```
<?php
phpinfo();
?>
```

Run that file to get your system settings (search for upload_max_filesize, etc);

Comment: Yes, I confirmed all the changes with phpinfo(). I'm completely stumped, as far as I can tell, it should be working.

Comment: In other words, I think this guy is trying to say Update your PHP.ini file and then try again.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried restarting your web server since making the changes?

Comment: I have. There is one line that is sticking out to me, the temporary upload location is commented out in the php.ini file. This shouldn't matter, it should default to something else, but could this possible have something to do with it?

Comment: Only if location is on limited disk partition or quota exhausted volume.